# Sidekiq active job , how to run one job at a time? (non-concurrent run)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

so, i have this job where it is able to be requested multiple times. however, when i run sidekiq, i want the jobs to be run one job at a time, in a queue. I am unable to find the function or the way to actually do this, please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that only one instance of your particular ActiveJob Job runs at a time, then implement a mutex lock. It's easy with a gem like [redis-mutex](https://rubygems.org/gems/redis-mutex/) (if you're already using Redis with sidekiq):

```
def perform
  RedisMutex.with_lock(:your_lock_name, expire: XXX_SECONDS) do
    # do something exclusively
  rescue RedisMutex::LockError
    Rails.logger.debug "Another job is running, exiting ..."
  end
end
```

Comment: this is awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can basically tune sidekiq so your queue work FIFO, from what I'm reading is what you want, the thing is that sidekiq is meant to handle parallel process, nevertheless if you want you can change your concurrency to 1 so one job is only executed at the time or try something what's metioned here.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#3-embrace-concurrency